# ¿Como escribir en archivos de la partición /data?

Tags: java, android, linux

Necesito tener acceso de escritura en archivos que mi aplicación creara por comandos root en la partición `/data` (No crea los archivo en el típico directorio `/data/data` si no en varios), pero mi código actual no me ha dado el resultado deseado:

```
public boolean creaArchivo2(String ruta, InputStream is)
    throws IOException {
boolean verdadero = false;
    final int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 4;

    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c mount -o remount,rw "+ruta);
    Process proc1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 "+ruta);
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(ruta));
    byte[] chunk = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
    int bytesLeidos = 0;

    while ( (bytesLeidos = is.read(chunk)) > 0) {

        os.write(chunk, 0, bytesLeidos);
    }
    os.close();

    return true;

}
```

Les explico mi código: Mi código  lo único que hace es tratar de establecer permisos de lectura y escritura en los archivos que se encuentran en la partición `/data` y luego copiar los datos de manera convencional con java, si mis comandos funcionaran pudiera copiar con facilidad, pero no funcionan.

Answer (score 0):

Para acceder dentro de `/data/data/my.package.com/` necesitas permisos especiales, [Root access](http://faqsandroid.com/root/).

Puedes encontrar información de como hace root tu dispositivo, **esto bajo tu propio riesgo**.

[Como rootear un Android](https://www.zonatopandroid.com/como-rootear-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Añade debajo de `OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(ruta));`:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c chmod -R 777 "+ruta);
```

*Esto establece que se puedan borrar, crear y editar los ficheros independientemente del usuario (ya que se ponen permisos de escritura, lectura y ejecución a todos los usuarios).